# Generated UUIDs behavior in postgres INSERT rule compared to the UPDATE rule

Tags: postgresql, uuid, rules

I have a postgres database with a single table. The primary key of this table is a generated UUID. I am trying to add a logging table to this database such that whenever a row is added or deleted, the logging table gets an entry. My table has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE configuration (
     id    uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
     name  text,
     data  json 
);
```

My logging table has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE configuration_log (
    configuration_id         uuid,
    new_configuration_data   json,
    old_configuration_data   json,
    "user"                   text,
    time                     timestamp
);
```

I have added the following rules:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE log_configuration_insert AS ON INSERT TO "configuration"
       DO INSERT INTO configuration_log VALUES (
          NEW.id,
          NEW.data,
          '{}',
          current_user,
          current_timestamp
       );

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE log_configuration_update AS ON UPDATE TO "configuration"
      WHERE NEW.data::json::text != OLD.data::json::text
      DO INSERT INTO configuration_log VALUES (
          NEW.id,
          NEW.data,
          OLD.data,
          current_user,
          current_timestamp
      );
```

Now, if I insert a value in the configuration table, the UUID in the configuration table and the configuration_log table are different. For example, the insert query

```
INSERT INTO configuration (name, data) 
       VALUES ('test', '{"property1":"value1"}')
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNn5.png)... the UUID is `c2b6ca9b-1771-404d-baae-ae2ec69785ac` in the configuration table whereas in the configuration_log table the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wc23.png)... the UUID id `16109caa-dddc-4959-8054-0b9df6417406`

However, the update rule works as expected. So if I write an update query as

```
UPDATE "configuration" 
    SET "data" = '{"property1":"abcd"}' 
    WHERE "id" = 'c2b6ca9b-1771-404d-baae-ae2ec69785ac';
```

The configuration_log table gets the correct UUID as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDK2K.png) i.e. `c2b6ca9b-1771-404d-baae-ae2ec69785ac`

I am using `NEW.id` in both the rules so I was expecting the same behavior. Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: How is the ID generated during insert? I don't see a default value nor a value supplied in the INSERT. Do you have a trigger for that?

Comment: Using uuid_generate_v4()... updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another good example why [rules should be avoided](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_rules)

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html#id-1.8.6.9.7):

> For any reference to NEW, the target list of the original query is searched for a corresponding entry. If found, that **entry's expression replaces the reference**.

So `NEW.id` is replaced with `uuid_generate_v4()` which explains why you are seeing a different value.

You should rewrite this to a trigger.

---

Btw: using `jsonb` is preferred over `json`, then you can also get rid of the (essentially incorrect) cast of the `json` column to `text` to compare the content.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... but why does it work fine in case of update and why the update rule doesn't behave in the same way?

Comment: @AsjadAsif: because the UPDATE statement does not use `uuid_generate_v4()`